# Is there a way to move row labels on the right side of a plotly heatmap?

Tags: r, plotly

I would like to know if it is possible to move the row labels on the right side of the heatmap, rather than on the left side or this cannot be moved in plotly.

```
data<-as.matrix(mtcars)
data[upper.tri(data)] <- NA

library(plotly)
plot_ly(x=colnames(data), y=rownames(data), z = data,colors = colorRamp(c("red","green")), type = "heatmap") %>%
  layout(
    xaxis=list(tickfont = list(size = 30), tickangle = 45),
    margin = list(l = 150, r = 50, b = 150, t = 0, pad = 4))
```

Comment: Where do you want to put legend?

Comment: Either left or right.This is not an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that we may use `yaxis = list(side = "right")` and adjust the colorbar position with `colorbar = list(x = -0.4)` (you may need to play a little with this value for your specific graph):

```
plot_ly(x = colnames(data), y = rownames(data), z = data,
        colors = colorRamp(c("red","green")), 
        type = "heatmap", colorbar = list(x = -0.4)) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(tickfont = list(size = 30), tickangle = 45), 
         yaxis = list(side = "right"), 
         margin = list(l = 150, r = 50, b = 150, t = 0, pad = 4))
```

[image]